# List all data types present in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, data-analysis

How can I list all datatypes present in a column **Name** of my dataframe **df**?

```
Name
1.0
XCY
```

Some might be strings, some might be floats etc.

Comment: Iterate through the column

Comment: If you want to get a list of types: `df['Name'].map(type).unique()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `map`, `agg` or `apply`:

```
>>> df['Name'].map(type).value_counts()
<class 'float'>    1
<class 'str'>      1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

---

```
>>> df['Name'].agg(type).value_counts()
<class 'float'>    1
<class 'str'>      1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

---

```
>>> df['Name'].apply(type).value_counts()
<class 'float'>    1
<class 'str'>      1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
>>>
```

---

To get the actual type names, use:

```
>>> df['Name'].map(lambda x: type(x).__name__).value_counts()
float    1
str      1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
>>>
```

You can change `map` to `apply` or `agg` and the code would still work as expected.

I use `type.__name__` to get the type name, more about it in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?__name__#definition.__name__):

> The name of the class, function, method, descriptor, or generator instance.

Comment: here, only the "class" ones are the data types, right? What does ```dtype: int64``` indicate?

Comment: @x89 It is `np.int64`, which is an integer, that is only the dtype of the result of `value_counts`, `1`